# @OneToOne Unidirectional with Shared Primary Key

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm learning JPA (2.1) and Hibernate (5.0.4).
In case of @OneToOne relation mapping exercise I would like to create unidirectional mapping based on shared key sequence generated. I'm able to do it in bidirectional way.

I was able to complete it using [[this blog]](http://www.techavalanche.com/2012/08/11/one-to-one-mapping-using-shared-primary-key-part-1/) but it looks like **hack** (code below)
Is there any better way to map such scenario?

*DDL:*

```
DROP TABLE HIBERNATE.T_USER_DETAILS;
DROP TABLE HIBERNATE.T_USERS;
DROP SEQUENCE HIBERNATE.USERS_SEQ;

-- ON HIBERNATE
CREATE TABLE HIBERNATE.T_USERS (
  ID                                NUMBER(15),
  NAME                              VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
  CONSTRAINT USER_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE HIBERNATE.T_USER_DETAILS (
  ID                                NUMBER(15),
  DETAILS                           VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
  CONSTRAINT UDETAILS_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT UDETAILS_FK FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES T_USERS(ID)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE HIBERNATE.USERS_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE NOCYCLE;
```

*UserModel:*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_USERS")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "users-sequence-generator", sequenceName = "USERS_SEQ", initialValue = 0, allocationSize = 1)
public class UserModel {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private UserDetailsModel userDetails;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "users-sequence-generator", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        if (userDetails != null) {
            userDetails.setId(id);
        }
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = EAGER, cascade = ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public UserDetailsModel getUserDetails() {
        return userDetails;
    }

    public void setUserDetails(UserDetailsModel userDetails) {
        this.userDetails = userDetails;
    }
}
```

*UserDetailsModel:*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetailsModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "details")
    private String details;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't really a hack, but why have the model be completely different from the database model?  The PrimaryKeyJoinColumn just tells the OneToOne mapping the id field is the foreign key to the UserDetailsModel's id field and that it is read-only, but your application is stuck having to always set the UserDetailsModel's id field manually based on the UserModel's id, and is completely reliant on the ID generation strategy.  If you use a UserDetailsModel -> UserModel reference and mark it as the ID, JPA will set it for you.

Comment: Hi @Chris, I posted wrong code of UserModel (wrong git branch - sorry for that) despite this thank You for Your comment. I will try to do more examples.

Comment: You could use and Embeddable instead of Table for UseDetailsModel then it would physically have the same ID.